# Is lazyloading of image necessary in cursor adapter

Tags: android, performance, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

i have been searching for a day about lazyloading in cursor adapter in a listview.

still i haven't found any useful solution.

Does cursor adapter requires lazyloading of contact images in a listview?

lazyloading must be invoked from bindview or newview ?

Could anyone help me pls?

Comment: Lazy loading is never really required but you can use it to improve the performance of loading images without blocking the ui thread.

Comment: Does loading contact photo in listview makes UI to lag ? Wont that be seamless ?

Comment: That depends on the size of the image. If you load a single small image, you can block the ui thread for some milliseconds. But for lists with many images it will be smoother if you load the images in an extra loading thread and display them when the loading is finished. It all depends on the user experience so you maybe want to test the blocking one before implementing a (more complex) lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks stephan.Still searching a proper solution to use cursor adapter with lazyloading of images.